# Magento 2.2.2 Change color of Add to Button

Tags: addtocart, magento2.2.2

I want to change **Color** of **Add to Cart Button** but i don't know how to do that.

Any help you will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: i don't want to copy every thing so i shared the related links and basic details that we need to take care

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a new Orange theme, which inherits from the Blank theme.
2. In the Orange theme directory add the overriding app/design/frontend/OrangeCo/orange/web/css/source/_theme.less file with the following code:

   ```
    //  Primary button
    @button-primary__color: @color-white;
    @button-primary__hover__color: @color-white;
    @button-primary__background: @color-orange-red1;
    @button-primary__hover__background: @color-orange-red4;
    @button-primary__border: 1px solid @color-orange-red2;
    @button-primary__hover__border: 1px solid @color-orange-red2;
   ```

Try this link

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css-overview.html

After use this command step by step

`php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`

`rm -rf var/cache/* var/generation/* var/page_cache/* var/view_preprocessed/*`

`rm -rf var/cache/* generated/*`

Comment: working now.@KamranKhan

Comment: its not working

Comment: proper step follow.

Comment: Yes i created. `OrangeCo/orange/web/css/source/_theme.css` in `app/design/frontend`. theme.xml and registration.php also exists. So don't know why its not working. My cache is disabled

Comment: check pub static folder generate or not..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74729/discussion-between-ravindrasinh-zala-and-kamrankhan).

Comment: @RavindrasinhZala Any help thanks https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/328933/57334

Answer (score 0):

[image: css]

source : Inchoo

You have to make changes as per this [CSS](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css-overview.html).

In short:

1) Create a new child theme as per above link

2) Never change css directly in pub files ,learn [.less](http://lesscss.org/)

3) Always work in developer mode `php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer`

**Run the following commands:**

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Comment: i am not able to understand this.

Comment: if you visit http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css-overview.html

you can easily understand that what you need to do

Comment: if in case it help , you can accept the appropriate answer to make Stack clean